# 'Should' instance variables or properties ever share getter/setters

Tags: oop, setter, code-duplication

Say I have a JavaScript object:

```
myObject = {
    oneArray: [],
    otherArray: [],

    setOneArray: function(){
        /*some code that sets the contents*/
    }

    setOtherArray: function(){
        /*again code that sets contents*/
    }
}
```

Now let's say that as it stands right now, the code of both 'setters' are identical. I'm duplicating effort and code, no two ways about it.  I could have written a single function for both and saved however-long in coding (or copying/pasting).  In the foreseeable future I've no reason to treat these any differently - so is this fundamentally a bad practice?

If context matters, both arrays are being pushed the same kind of data - strings - but from different parts of a JSON file.

Comment: How would you specify which array to set? Passing in a variable? I think that would indicate that they need to be two different functions. Typically you have a 1:1 relationship for getters/setters to properties and some sort of convention for field name to getter/setter (array/set_array, otherArray/set_otherArray)name.

Comment: If your setter is non-trivial, and you want to avoid duplication, you should wrap your arrays (or add to their prototypes) the setter method.  This takes care of the instance passing implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and say it: Yes, it's a bad practice to duplicate code. One of the first principles developers should learn is [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Having duplicate code just increases the chance for them to get out of sync.

What you could do is still have bother setters, but have them each only call another method that contains the same code. If that ever changes one day, then you can get rid of the common method and have your setters simply be different at that point.